# How to combine these to alter statements into a single alter statement

Tags: sql, unique-constraint, alter-table

How to combine these two alter statements into a single alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD CONSTRAINT  A_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (A_PK_ID)
  REFERENCES C(A_PK_ID);

 ALTER TABLE A
 ADD CONSTRAINT B_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (D_PK_ID)
  REFERENCES E(D_PK_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MS SQL or MySQL, it would be like this

```
ALTER TABLE A 
    ADD CONSTRAINT A_FK FOREIGN KEY (A_PK_ID) REFERENCES C(A_PK_ID),
    ADD CONSTRAINT B_FK FOREIGN KEY (D_PK_ID) REFERENCES E(D_PK_ID);
```